# Heroku Server Python Socket Not accepting client connections

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I have two files name Client.py and server.py

client.py:

```
import socket
import pickle
host = "NAME OF HEROKU SERVER"
port = 80
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((host, port))
clientSocket.send(pickle.dumps("SOME OBJECT"))
```

server.py:

```
import socket
host = ""
port = 3000
encodingType = 'utf-8'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen()
conn, add = s.accept()
```

I am able to deploy server file in heroku. But when I try to connect to heroku server from client, the server is not accepting any client connections. I went saw this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets#deploy where they use flask for websocket send and receive, but I use pickle and strings for sending and receiving. So I find it hard to use flask. Is there any other way? I want to make heroku server accept client connections without Flask.